# Null Error when passing 10 names to a method in an arraylist

Tags: java

I want to simply pass 10 names to a method in an arraylist but i'm getting a null error. Any ideas?

```
public class JavaApplication17 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);        
        String [] names = new String[10];       
        System.out.println("Enter 10 names: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){            
            names[i] = scan.nextLine(); 
            arrayMethod(names);
        }
    }

    private static void arrayMethod(String arr[]) {
       for (String a : arr) {
           System.out.printf( "%s",a);
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: move `arrayMethod(names);` out of the loop

Comment: Ahh stupid mistake.. I spent about an hour trying to figure it out. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

After reading one element of the array you are trying to print all of it (a string array is initialized as an array of nulls, I’m guessing) and the formatting of null as a string probably throws an exception?

Comment: I pointed at the source of his problem, I didn’t make assumptions about what his code is supposed to do and I didn’t spoonfeed him, but to say I didn’t answer his question (ideas why he got a null error) is just false.

Answer (score 0):

Everything else is fine. You just need to take your method call outside the for loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] names = new String[10];
    System.out.println("Enter 10 names: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        names[i] = scan.nextLine();
    }
    arrayMethod(names);
}

private static void arrayMethod(String arr[]) {
    for (String a : arr)
        System.out.printf("%s", a);
}
```

When the method call is in the loop, the method is called and the entire List is iterated through when there are still uninitialized values in the array. Taking the method call out of the for loop solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize an array with the size, the unassigned indexes will contain the default value which for String is *null*. Then you try to print the whole array after every input and this will print the input value and *null* for the rest of the array.

If you need to print all at once simply move the `arrayMethod(names)` out of the loop as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String [] names = new String[10];

        System.out.println("Enter 10 names: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

            names[i] = scan.nextLine();

        }

        arrayMethod(names);
}
```

If you need to print the name after the input then change the code as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String [] names = new String[10];

    System.out.println("Enter 10 names: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        names[i] = scan.nextLine();

        arrayMethod(names[i]);
    }
}
private static void arrayMethod(String name)

{

    System.out.println(name);
}
```